# how to change visual studio 2017 working directory running Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have `Visual Studio 2017` and want to run `Python`.

Everything I choose part of the code and select "send to interactive window", it showed error, i.e.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> NameError: name 'BHI_DLL' is not defined

I check the working directory and it always show

```
os.getcwd()
```

> 'C:\Python27'

How can I change the working directory to the folder where all my files are saved?

thank you very much

Comment: Inconvenient I know but how about `os.chdir()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.CodeRunner) extension to run your code instead of the Interactive window.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, you can also use chdir

```
os.chdir('c:/temp')
```

just replace the directory with the one you want.